# Execute task after a certain amount of time after PC start

Tags: scheduled-tasks, keyboard-input

For a museum installation I need to find a way (I guess with task sheduler) to do this scenario :

1 - Museum's staff start the pc (Windows 10)

2 - "Resolume" (a software) start at launch of the pc (Already achieve this, I've put it in the application list that run at start).

3 - **- Then after a certain amount of time (because Resolume project need time to initialize), execute a macro/keyboard input that I have configured as a "starting key" to Resolum.**

So the staff doesn't have to do anything execpt starting the PC everymorning :)

The part in bold is where I struggle, I don't find a way to do a task after x times after pc starts. And in this case I guess the task is launching a script that will do this keyboard input (If you have answer to do this asswell, I'll take it, thanks).

Forgive me for grammar errors, I'm french and I wrote this quickly, museum open tomorow (I received the projet this morning)

Comment: This is OS dependent, please list your operating system in the question

Comment: Windows 10, sorry.